# Can a Kazakh national transit in Dubai without a visa?

Tags: transit-visas, dxb, airport-terminals, kazakh-citizens

I am a Kazakh passport holder.

I'm travelling from Delhi via SpiceJet to Dubai, landing at Terminal 1 in the early morning. On the same day in the late evening I have a flight to Astana via flydubai from Terminal 2. I do not have a Dubai visa.

Can I transit from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 without a visa?

I am asking because of many variations to this question. Some say a visa is necessary, others write its an internal transfer by bus not requiring visa. So, I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

To stay airside and, therefore, not require a transit visa at [Dubai International (DXB)](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/), you go to the transfer desk when you arrive at Terminal 1 (the C Gates), and **take the shuttle bus** to Terminal 2 (F Gates) [emphasis mine].

> **[Find your transfer desk](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections)**
>
> Our dedicated transfer desks give you the boarding pass for your onward flight.
>
> Find them by:
>
> - following the signs
> - using our interactive maps
> - asking May I Help You staff
> - consulting one of our Information Zones
>
> **Terminal 1 (C Gates)**
>
> - Use transfer desk A if you’re flying with Emirates or Qantas
> - Use transfer desks B and C for all other airlines
> - Transfer desk E (on the lower level) is for passengers transferring from Terminal 2
>
> **Moving between terminals**
>   When connecting between A, B or C Gates, all the gates are within walking distance. The only exceptions are the A Gates. For these you take the airport train.
>
> If you are connecting to or from F Gates (located across the tarmac), your airline will tell you what to do. Services include free shuttle buses, Marhaba service and public transport.
>
> **Transit Between Terminals**
>   For passenger transiting between the terminals in Dubai for connecting flights, there is a free shuttle bus running.
>
> ***Note that to use this bus you do not have to go through immigration and this service is only for airside transits and runs roughly every 10 minutes and can take up to 15 minutes to reach another terminal.***

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=ae&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours

So no, you do **not** need a visa. If you can't find any airside signs for T2, contact the transfer desk and they'll help you.

Answer (score -1):

DXB allows airside transfer and no transit visa is required for Kazakhstan citizens if the flight connection is under 24 hours.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would expand your answer to add a reference, such as Timatic search results or UAE visa requirements.

Comment: It is not clear that airside transfer is possible between Terminal 2 and the others; that is why the question was asked, and why it has not been closed as a duplicate.